# Javascript Function Call Order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object that I am configuring over multiple steps and I am simply to trying to organize the code better. Here is an example:

```
  var myObj = {};

  function one(obj) {
      //Do a whole bunch of stuff;
      obj.count = 0;
  }

  function two(obj) {
      obj.count += 1;
  }

  one(myObj);
  two(myObj);
```

When function 2 is called, am I guaranteed that obj.count already exists (because function one was completely ran)? I understand there are other ways I could do this, but I am simply wondering about this case and what's happening. These are not async functions either such as a database call or file reader.

Comment: yes, because javascript executes synchronously your actions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are guaranteed that `obj.count` exists. JavaScript executes synchronously.